# Can I assign a shortcut for a command line utility

Tags: intellij-idea

Is it possible to assign a shortcut to a specific command you want executed in the terminal?

Using IntelliJ idea 14 in ubuntu

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you trying to assign "shortcuts" to be used on linux terminal? If that is the case, what you want is to [add alias to your shell](http://askubuntu.com/questions/154640/how-to-add-an-alias-to-a-command-in-terminal) (editting the ~/.bashrc file is you use bash, or ~/.zshrc if you use zsh). What makes your question confusing to me is the fact that you mention IntelliJ idea, so I wonder if you are actually asking something specific to Java / the IDE.

Comment: @Victor I want to open the terminal (Alt + F12), and write a command from the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

You can record a macro (Edit->Macros) that starts from Alt+F12 and includes your terminal command. Then map it to whatever shortcut you want (File->Settings->Keymap.) Search for the name you gave the macro you just recorded, and assign the shortcut.